# *ngFor directive isn't working with mat-expansion panel. Need solution

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

when I am adding *ngFor with mat-expansion panel in my html file, it is not letting it work. The moment I remove it, it works fine. Here are some screenshots of the files.

I tried with and without *ngfor and without it, that works but with it, it doesnt.

html

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor = "let post of posts">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{ post.title }}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       {{ post.content }}
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  posts : [
    { title : "this is first title" , content : "This is 1 content" },
    {title : "this is second title", content : "This is 2 content"},
    {title : "this is third title", content : "This is 3 content"}
  ];
}
```

when I am adding *ngFor with mat-expansion panel in my html file, it is not letting it work. The moment I remove it, it works fine. Here are some screenshots of the files.

I tried with and without *ngfor and without it, that works but with it, it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your post array in wrong way. `:` is used to declare the type of property so use `=` instead

```
posts = [ 
    { title : "this is first title" , content : "This is 1 content" },
    {title : "this is second title", content : "This is 2 content"},
    {title : "this is third title", content : "This is 3 content"}
  ];
```